# Get float value from TMP_InputField

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to get float value from TMP_InputField component with Content Type set as Decimal Number? Following solution:
`float value = float.Parse (myTmpInputField.text);`
gave me exception:
`floatFormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Answer (score -1):

Try

float value = 0F;
bool success = float.TryParse(myTmpInputField.text, out value);

or use try/catch